# How to tell if my iOS 13 background task has run?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying out iOS Background Task for the first time.  Following the [sample WWDC'19 code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/refreshing_and_maintaining_your_app_using_background_tasks), I set up a simple app that sets a `UserDefaults` key's value to 1 in the `ViewController.viewDidLoad()` and set it to 2 in the background task.  I have the value printed before entering background and upon returning to foreground.  The value consistently prints as 1, even after letting the app sit in the background overnight. Is my background task not run?  Or could it be that my `UserDefaults` value is not synchronized between the foreground and background tasks, as discussed in several stackoverflow questions? Or am I doing something else wrong?  Any pointer appreciated.

I have checked the "Background fetch" item in "Background Modes" under "Signing & Capabilities" and I have also added "com.example.BGTask.refresh" as "item 0" under "Permitted background task scheduler" in my `Info.plist`. I'm running the app on device, tethered to Xcode.

iOS 13.5.1, Xcode 11.5

**AppDelegate.swift**:

```swift
import UIKit
import BackgroundTasks

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: "com.example.BGTask.refresh", using: nil) { task in
            self.handleAppRefresh(task: task as! BGAppRefreshTask)
        }
        return true
    }

    func scheduleAppRefresh() {
        let request = BGAppRefreshTaskRequest(identifier: "com.example.BGTask.refresh")
        request.earliestBeginDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 15*60)
        do {
            try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
        } catch {
            print("Could not schedule app refresh: \(error)")
        }
    }

    func handleAppRefresh(task: BGAppRefreshTask) {
        scheduleAppRefresh()

        task.expirationHandler = {
            task.setTaskCompleted(success: false)
        }

        UserDefaults.standard.set(2, forKey: "bgtask")
        task.setTaskCompleted(success: true)
    }


    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle
    // rest of templated AppDelegate.swift
```

**SceneDelegate.swift**:
Following [this tutorial](https://www.andyibanez.com/posts/modern-background-tasks-ios13/), I call `scheduleAppRefresh()` in `SceneDelegate` instead of `AppDelegate` and have modified these two functions:

```swift
    func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
        print("didBecomeActive: ", UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "bgtask"))
    }

    func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        print("didEnterBackground: ", UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "bgtask"))
        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).scheduleAppRefresh()
    }
```

Finally, in **ViewController.swift**:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        UserDefaults.standard.set(1, forKey: "bgtask")
        print("viewDidLoad: ", UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "bgtask"))
    }
}
```

This is what I get printed out on the Xcode console:

```sh
viewDidLoad:  1
didBecomeActive:  1
                        // tap the Home button
didEnterBackground:  1
                        // after a suitably long time, tap the app icon
didBecomeActive:  1
```

Why doesn't `UserDefaults.shared.integer(forKey: "bgtask")` get incremented by the second `didBecomeActive`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after I watch wwdc2019

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/707/

The task will be executed only when the system decides to do so

You can check to this forum discussion link too :

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/124320

Comment: Wahyudimas, thank you for the answer, but I have waited more than 15 minutes before bringing the task back to the foreground.  Actually, I have even tried waiting overnight.  Still the `UserDefaults` value didn't get changed.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm aware of the "when the system decides to do so" aspect of background tasking.  I just didn't (and still don't) expect that to include "never." I'd rather hope someone can point out an error in my code.

Comment: I know this is a very late post, but curious if you ever got an answer to this @AndyHill

Comment: @Stavros_S Unfortunately no. It seems like one may be able to use BGProcessing instead of BGAppRefresh, but I haven't pursued that further, deciding to look into the use of push notification instead. That may have longer term viability, conforming to platform preference.

Comment: You can schedule a local notification while in background task, so that when notification appears - you know that bg task has run.

Comment: Only way i found to check the correct implementation of my code calling the background task is with: e -l objc -- (void)[[BGTaskScheduler sharedScheduler] _simulateLaunchForTaskWithIdentifier:@"YOUR_REFRESH_TASK_ID || YOUR_PROCESSING_TASK_ID"]
Based on this article: https://uynguyen.github.io/2020/09/26/Best-practice-iOS-background-processing-Background-App-Refresh-Task/

Answer (score 2):

Well, I got background **processing** to work.  Xcode console output:

```
viewDidLoad:  1
didBecomeActive:  1
didEnterBackground:  1
didBecomeActive:  1
didEnterBackground:  1
                           // after about 15 minutes
didBecomeActive:  2
didEnterBackground:  2
                           // after staying in background overnight (~8 hours)
didBecomeActive:  19
didEnterBackground:  19
```

Instead of "Background fetch," I ticked "Background processing" in "Background Modes" under "Signing & Capabilities".

**AppDelegate.swift:**

```sh
import UIKit
import BackgroundTasks

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: "com.example.BGTask.refresh", using: nil) { task in
            self.handleAppRefresh(task: task as! BGProcessingTask)
        }
        return true
    }

    func scheduleAppRefresh() {

        let request = BGProcessingTaskRequest(identifier: "com.example.BGTask.refresh")
        request.requiresNetworkConnectivity = false
        request.requiresExternalPower = false

        do {
            try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
        } catch {
            print("Could not schedule app refresh: \(error)")
        }
    }

    func handleAppRefresh(task: BGProcessingTask) {
        scheduleAppRefresh()
        
        task.expirationHandler = {
            task.setTaskCompleted(success: false)
        }
        
        // increment instead of a fixed number
        UserDefaults.standard.set(UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "bgtask")+1, forKey: "bgtask")

        task.setTaskCompleted(success: true)
    }
    
    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle
    // rest of templated AppDelegate.swift
```

And no other changes to the other files.

Now why does BGProcessing work while BGAppRefresh doesn't?